# Best way to trouble shoot hardware (FPS in game issue)

Tags: laptop, dell-xps, fps

I have a Dell Studio xps, i7 core processor, with a Radeon HD 5730. When playing league of legends, my laptop goes into warp drive (fans pushing pretty hard) and of course my computer warms up. My FPS in game (graphics on lowest settings) drops from 60 to about 7 then averages out to about 15.

My question is this, how can I figure out what's causing this problem? I've already ensured my drivers are all up to date. When playing the game I turn off all resource hungry programs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it's overheating - when that happens the CPU automatically throttles your clock speed. Can you try recording temperature with a program like SpeedFan?

Comment: In addition the above, it also seems that the graphics card is throttling itself (as indicated by the frame drop).

Comment: Have you tried to tone down the graphic settings of League of Legends and repeat the problem?

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard League settings are always at the lowest they can go. My brother has the same type of computer as I do (exactly same specs) and he doesn't have the same issue I have. On that note, I'm on a new install of Windows.

Comment: @user55325 & Yassarikhan786 I'll try the speedFan thing and make an edit with the results.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of performance drop you are experiencing is definitely a overheating issue.

My Tip:-

1) - Install SpeedFan and check the temperature when the system is idle. If the idle temperature of Graphics Card and Intel processor is above 55C then you definitely have a overheating problem. I would advise you to open the laptop and clean the heatsink fan and apply a good quality thermal paste on the processor.

2) - Even after Step 1, if the overheating issue still persists then chances are that the heatsink has worned out buy a brand new heatsink for your laptop model. You can get from ebay.

I've a Dell Studio 1558 laptop and had overheating issues and took it lightly and after a while my laptop stopped working, I ended up buying a new heatsink but the damage to the Graphics card was done and it's not working now, luckily I've Intel corei3 processor which has a integrated graphics so I'm currently using my laptop on that one the ATI Radeon isn't working. I think Corei7 doesn't come with an integrated graphics so if you end up ruining the graphics card you may have to buy a new motherboard which will be expensive, so don't take the overheating lightly.